# Error : : jQuery was not called

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, cross-domain

Here is my ajax call.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://example.com/v1/search?keyword=r",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (responseString) {
        alert(responseString);
    },
    error: function (xhr, errorType, exception) {
        var errorMessage = exception || xhr.statusText;
        alert(errorMessage);
    }
});
```

Response from my example url

```
    {
    "response": [{
        "attributes": {
            "type": "enge",
            "url": "/services/data/v24.0/sobjects/Challenge__c/a0GZ0000005Vvh4MAC"
        },
        "name": "Really",
        "end_date": "2013-02-07T15:26:00.000+0000",
        "total": 350.0,
        "registered_members": 0.0,
        "id": "30",
        "type": "Design",
        "id": "a0GZ0000005Vvh4MAC",
        "start_date": "2012-11-19T16:52:00.000+0000",
        "description": "This is my really cool challenge",
        "remaining_days": 28.0,
        "categories__r": [{
            "attributes": {
                "type": "Category__c",
                "url": "/services/data/Category__c/a08Z0000000RNI2IAO"
            },
            "id": "0RNI2IAO",
            "display_name": "Andy"
        }, {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "Category__c",
                "url": "/services/Category__c/a08Z0000000RNI3IAO"
            },
            "id": "a0O",
            "display_name": "ADR"
        }]
    }

    }],
    "count": 1
}
```

i'm trying to make an cross domain call and getting error

```
jQuery180014405992737595236_1357861668479 was not called
```

***Update***

Well i tried to use dataType:"json" but at that point getting error

```
No Transport
```

Comment: Is your remote page emitting a properly formed JSONP response? `callback({ /* json */ })`

Comment: Yep, the response is JSON, not JSONP.

Comment: @FelixKling well i tried using dataType:json but getting error "No Transport"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That suggests either a network error or an end point that doesn't return a JSONP response.

(I'm guessing the DNS lookup failure I get when testing it is because that isn't your real URL (please use `example.com` for example URLs, that is what it is there for) if not, then that is your problem).

Comment: It's the endpoint not serving correct jsonp, if it was a network error he would get the according error code instead.

Comment: @jade — That's a JSON response, not a JSONP response. You need to wrap it with a function call to the function specified in the callback argument (and use an application/javascript content type instead of application/json)

Comment: the main point is in fact the server must answer jQuery180014405992737595236_1357861668479({"theJson":"value})  your answer is rude

Answer (score 5):

It's an incorrect JSONP Response. The server needs to process the `callback=nameOfCallbackFunction` argument of the `GET` Request and serve it as a function wrapper.

The proper response then should look like this:

```
nameOfCallbackFunction({"yourjson": "here"});
```

Comment: so u mean that's not a jsonp response but json response.I tried with json dataType but getting No Transport error.I have updated question

Comment: @jade Is this a crossdomain call (Pointing to a different location than where your page comes from)? If yes, you can only use JSONP or use [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) to prevent [SOP](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-Origin-Policy) errors.

Comment: well actually i dont know if its cross domain.I got an error while not using cross domain "No Transport", so just googled and some suggested using cross domain would resolve the issue

Comment: ok i just used $.support.cors = true; before ajax call but its giving error Access Denied

Comment: Well, "No Transport" or "Access Denied" sound like a typical violation of SOP. Are you testing from your local machine (localhost) and/or using Internet Explorer? You need to either use CORS or JSONP, no other option for you.

Comment: well i'm testing from localhost using an html page, it not hosted

Comment: You cannot make crossdomain calls with localhost unless using a development with experimental flags.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread but have struggled to get a cross domain ajax example working. I read much about using dataType: jsonp and support.cors = true but got a 200 - success but a parseerror.

I then read in this thread about using one or the other. I then changed the dataType: to json and left the support.cors = true and it worked. Finally . . .

This may help someone else who encounters the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you have the error JQueryXXXX is because there is an error in the url you are calling, you need to introduce "?callback=?", so looks like:

```
"http://example.com/v1/search?callback=?keyword=r"
```

Also If you call a .php remember:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
```