# Cross domain ajax request using JSONP

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, jsonp

I need to get data at my application from other domain. I'm tring to use jsonp but every time I have error '80020101'

Here is my code (ASP.NET MVC 4) at 'other domain'

```
 public ActionResult Test()
 {
    return Json(new { foo = "bar", baz = "Blech" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
 public string Test2()
 {
    return "aaa";
 }
```

And here is my ajax method what sends a request

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'https://192.168.0.61/CryptoProTestTool/Home/Test2/',
   type: 'GET',
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      alert("error"); 
   },
   success: function(json) {
      alert("success");
   }
   });
```

What's wrong? Why do I always have an error in this simple example? I have issue with Test and Test2 data...

Manual testing shows that service sends data
[image]

**EDIT 1:** I have an error "Can not finish action. error 80020101." at error function of ajax request.
I tried to change Test2 like this

```
public ActionResult Test2()
{
  return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Hello world!');</script>"); 
}
```

But have the same issue

**Edit2:**
Hi again!
I was told working solution but after I run it issue appears.

```
 public ActionResult Test2()
 {
    return Content("MyMethod('test12345');"); 
 }
```

And Javascript code:

```
function onPageLoad() {
   CheckCryptoProAvailable();
}

function CheckCryptoProAvailable() {

  $.ajax({
     url: 'https://192.168.0.61/CryptoProTestTool/Home/Test2/',
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: "jsonp",
     error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert("error = " + error.toString()); 
     },
     success: function(json) {

     }
  });

}

function MyMethod(testValue){
 alert(testValue);

}
```

Everything goes ok and MyMethod is called after request. But after it I see a window from ajax request error handler. What's wrong again?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you get this error? "aaa" is not valid javascript. to use jsonp, you should return something like

```
callbackFunc("aaa");
```

Comment: Should I for use jsonp always return javascript? 
Like 
public string Test2()
{
    return "SomeFunction(aaa);";
 }

Comment: I used simple javascript (see Edit1) but issue still present

Comment: Test2 still invalid. <script> tag added by jquery, you only need alert('Hello world!'); Next thing. You should use this only after document ready.

Comment: Thanks, you showed me a solution. But after it strange issue appears (see Edit2)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255502/error-jquery-was-not-called. I didn't knew that, but GET method should accept 'callback' argument and emit code like callback(...).