# JQuery AJAX Error failed to execute send on xmlhttprequest

Tags: jquery, bing-maps

I am trying to execute bing map REST API using JQuery AJAX method. The Rest URL shows correct results in browser. But when I execute same URL using AJAX method of JQuery it seems to be not working and I am getting following exception:

**"Netowrk error: failed to execute send on xmlhttprequest"**

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'text',
        url: 'http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/47.64054,-122.12934?includeEntityTypes=Address&includeNeighborhood=0&include=ciso2&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        success: function (result) {
            alert("working");
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError, request, error) {
            alert('xrs.status = ' + xhr.status + '\n' +
                  'thrown error = ' + thrownError + '\n' +
                  'xhr.statusText = ' + xhr.statusText + '\n' +
                  'request = ' + request + '\n' +
                  'error = ' + error);
        }
    });
```

When I open the same URL in browser I can see the result in JSON format.

Please help!!!

Comment: Use  dataType : 'JSON'    in your ajax call

Comment: Just a thought here but have you tried removing the asyn = false? 
Perhaps you have other ajaxcalls that get executed before this one is finished which give you this problem.

Edit: After reading @sunil coment above i realized that his answer is more likely to be the soloution to your problem. Although i will leave the coment as an note that you can end up having problems when you have async = false while making several ajax calls.

Comment: @sunil I have changed dataType to JSON but still getting same error. Any thoughts?

Comment: ajax would work only on the same server means if you give different url which have different server other than your existing server then it would not work

Comment: @Coder2599 can you share it on jsfiddle? It seems difficult as you have your API key in a call,,but I can't sort it out by looking to your code only

Comment: Is there any workaround if we would need to get data from external URLs?

Comment: @sunil I want to read JSON response from this URL `http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/47.64054,-122.12934?includeEntityTypes=Address&includeNeighborhood=0&include=ciso2&key=Ar19hs9V6usMWGZWEyY9hiF5hu8JaOGJkOUL2hMhgyXUicCjar3UuzWrlSN_eFbK`

Comment: @Coder2599, I tested it, issue is from server side that is CORS cross origin support, that's y u unable to make a API call. So try disabling CORS for your browser. If you are using Chrome, then you can find on google how to allow CORS in Chrome..It will solve your problem

Comment: I was facing the same error when making a GET request (not to bing map. Just another api of our own server). Found out that I am sending a huge payload. Changed method from GET to POST. (The api server is also controlled by us. So could change method in backend). Problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other response you need to make the data type jsonp. However it should be a GET request to the Location service as cross domain POST requests are not supported. You can find a good blog post on using the Bing Maps services with various JavaScript frameworks like jQuery here: https://blogs.bing.com/maps/2015/03/05/accessing-the-bing-maps-rest-services-from-various-javascript-frameworks/

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem of the `Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest'` (only appearing in Chrome) and finally found that the problem was on the `async: false` option used.
I suppose this error arises because of trying to make synchronous request to foreign domains, which is not supported, as explained in [jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation

Answer (score 0):

I had to decode your question a bit. It looks like you are using MS' virtualearth.net/Bing geolocation `find by point` API:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701710.aspx

Reading their documentation a bit, it looks like you are trying to send lat/long coordinates and receive address information back in return. You have set the `includeNeighborhood` flag to 0 in your URL, which means you don't that information (not sure if that was intentional).

As for the AJAX jQuery call, I think the error is in the call format. It's probably a type `POST`, because you are posting information to the Bing API and then receiving results. A `GET` request would be for a read-only API.

Example of how I would write this call (note the `type` and `dataType` parameters). You should send `JSONP` instead of JSON if want to use a callback function with the data you receive (likely scenario).

```
 $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: "JSONP",
   url: 'http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/47.64054,-122.12934?includeEntityTypes=Address&includeNeighborhood=0&include=ciso2&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
   success: function (resultPass) {
     console.log(resultPass);
   },
   error: function (resultFail) {
     console.log(resultFail);
   }
 });
```

Comment: I modified code as per your guidelines and it seems the response is success but still I am getting exception/error in response message:
`xrs.status = 200
thrown error = Error: jQuery1113033110253675520873_1442236288411 was not called
xhr.statusText = success
request = undefined
error = undefined`

Comment: Sometimes that error is related to an endpoint data response mismatch: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255502/error-jquery-was-not-called

Comment: Tried JSON, and got this response:
`xrs.status = 0
thrown error = 
xhr.statusText = error
request = undefined
error = undefined`

Comment: Can you update the question with the revised call the error? Hard to read down here.